# save and find json string in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, database-design, mongodb-java

I'm building a logging application that does the following:

- gets JSON strings from many loggers continuously and saves them to a db
- serves the collected data as a per logger bulk

my intention is to use a document based NoSQL storage to have the bulk structure right away. After some research I decided to go for MongoDB because of the following features:
- comprehensive functions to insert data into existing structures ($push, (capped) collection)
- automatic sharding with a key I choose (so I can shard on a per logger basis and therefore serve bulk data in no time - all data already being on the same db server)

The JSON I get from the loggers looks like this:

```
[
  {"bdy":{
    "cat":{"id":"36494h89h","toc":55,"boc":99},
    "dataT":"2013-08-12T13:44:03Z","had":0,
    "rng":23,"Iss":[{"id":10,"par":"dim, 10, dak"}]
  },"hdr":{
    "v":"0.2.7","N":2,"Id":"KBZD348940"}
  }
]
```

The logger can send more than one element in the same array. I this example it is just one.

I started coding in Java with the mongo driver and the first problem I discovered was: I have to parse my with no doubt valid JSON to be able to save it in mongoDB. I learned that this is due to BSON being the native format of MongoDB. I would have liked to forward the JSON string to the db directly to save that extra execution time.

so what I do in a first Java test to save just this JSON string is:

```
String loggerMessage = "...the above JSON string...";
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("logData");
DBObject message = (DBObject) JSON.parse(loggerMessage);
coll.insert(message);
```

the last line of this code causes the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not: [_id]
at org.bson.types.BasicBSONList._getInt(BasicBSONList.java:161)
at org.bson.types.BasicBSONList._getInt(BasicBSONList.java:152)
at org.bson.types.BasicBSONList.get(BasicBSONList.java:104)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.apply(DBCollection.java:767)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.apply(DBCollection.java:756)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:220)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:204)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:76)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:60)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:105)
at mongomockup.MongoMockup.main(MongoMockup.java:65)
```

I tried to save this JSON via the mongo shell and it works perfectly.

How can I get this done in Java?
How could I maybe save the extra parsing?
What structure would you choose to save the data? Array of messages in the same document, collection of messages in single documents, ....

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611255/error-when-creating-object-in-collection-in-mongolab-basicbsonlist-can-only-wor)

Comment: Have you tried removing the `[]` around your JSON string? If you remove them it shuold work fine.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work because of the array. You need a BasicDBList to be able to save multiple messages. Here is my new solution that works perfectly:

```
    BasicDBList data = (BasicDBList) JSON.parse(loggerMessage);
    for(int i=0; i < data.size(); i++){
        coll.insert((DBObject) data.get(i));
    }
```